# C# or .NET Flushing Keyboard Buffer

Tags: c#, keyboard, buffer, flush

How do I flush the keyboard buffer in C# using Windows Forms?

I have a barcode scanner which acts like a keyboard. If a really long barcode is scanned and the cancel button is hit on the form, I need the keyboard buffer to be cleared. So I need to flush and ignore all pending input. I need the buffer cleared because if the barcode contains spaces, the spaces are processed as button clicks which is unecessary.

Comment: What do you mean by keyboard buffer?  Do you want to flush and ignore all pending input that you haven't processed yet?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Yes...for example I have a barcode scanner which acts like a keyboard...if a really long barcode is scanned and the cancel button is hit on the form, I need the keyboard buffer to be cleared. So I need to flush and ignore all pending input.

Comment: I need the buffer cleared because if the barcode contains spaces, the spaces are processed as button clicks which is unecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this. The keystrokes go into the event queue for the main event loop. Any action you take to cancel these keystrokes will be placed in the queue after the keystrokes.

The event loop will only get to your cancel action after the keystrokes have been processed. You can only cancel the keystrokes based on some event that happens in the middle of the keystroke sequence.

Answer (score 5):

```cs
while (Console.KeyAvailable) { Console.ReadKey(true); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `KeyPreview` on the Form to `true`, then catch the `KeyPress` event and set `e.Handled` to `true` if cancel was clicked.

**EDIT**: Catch the **Form's** KeyPress event

Answer (score 1):

@Chris:

`Console.KeyAvailable` threw an exception on me because the Console did not have focus.

The exception message was helpful, though. It suggested using `Console.In.Peek()` to read in that instance.

I thought it would be worth noting here as an alternate solution and for posterity.

```
 if (-1 < Console.In.Peek()) {
     Console.In.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the form, and force all processing to occur with DoEvents whilst it's disabled.  The Controls should reject any keystokes because they are disabled.
Then re-enable the form.

```
this.Enabled = false;
Application.DoEvents();
this.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do BIOS level flushing [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/43993](https://web.archive.org/web/20120127131309/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/43993) but I would advise against this low level approach since Windows also does keyboard buffering on a higher level.

The best way seems to be to eat any arriving char while a specific flag is set. As SLaks suggests I would set `KeyPreview` to true and set `e.Handled` to true either in `KeyPress` or in `KeyDown`.. should make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's a old question but I got the same issue and I found a good way to do it...
When **Application.DoEvent()** is called, the keystoke buffer call the KeyPress event but _keypress is set to false, so it'll skip all them, after that _keypress return to true to be ready for another keypress event !

```
public bool _keypress;
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_keypress)
    {
        _keypress = true;
        // instructions
    }
    Application.DoEvents();
    _keypress = false;
}
```

Comment: This is not C# code, so it does not answer the question

Comment: @a0poster my bad, done !