# keybd_event: global keystrokes simulations show up in unexpected manner in C# Console

Tags: c#, keyboard, console, key, simulation

What happens when you open a console and keep the `a`-button pressed for a second?

The output would better be
`aaaaaaaa +- a few a's`. So when I simulate pressing the `a`-button and releasing it after a second, if find it strange that the output of this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

is a single `a`. Ok fine, I can live with that. I'll just make a loop to repeat this any number of times. Suppose I want the `a` character 5 times, I expect the following code to suffice:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int VK_A = 0x41;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        keybd_event(VK_A, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
        keybd_event(VK_A, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Thread.Sleep(4000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I was surprised that the output is

```
done
aaaaa
```

Note that the "done" is *before* the `a`'s, which I find strange, and the `a`'s appear simultaneously when `Console.ReadLine()` is reached.... as if that statement triggers the letters to appear.... If you want to try this yourself, you also need:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern void keybd_event(byte vk, byte bscan, uint flags, int extrainfo);
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;
```

I have exactly the same issue with the newer function `SendInput`. Can someone explain the logic behind this to me?

Comment: And I'm aware that simulating keystrokes is usually not the right thing to do. So don't mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the output buffer isn't being flushed between keystrokes. There is a similar post here:

[C# or .NET Flushing Keyboard Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978091/c-or-net-flushing-keyboard-buffer)

The post indicates that flushing the keyboard isn't really possible. There are a few posts online about how to do it -- most are similar to: http://myarticles-csharpnetstuff.blogspot.com/2009/09/tip-flush-keyboard-buffer-in-c.html

And use the following method (copied from link):

```
private static void FlushKeyboard()
{
     while (Console.In.Peek() != -1)
         Console.In.Read();
}
```

I personally don't like this way because you end up doing a lot of unnecessary read operations. What exactly are you trying to do here? Is it really important for the "aaaa" line to appear before "done" ?

-- Dan