# Console.In.Peek() resulting in not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to upgrade a winforms vs2005/.net2.0 project to vs2010/.net4.0. Users can print labels. During the print, if the user hits enter key multiple times, it needs to be discarded hence the following code is in place.

```
Friend Sub FlushKeyboard()
        While Console.In.Peek() <> -1
            Console.In.Read()
        End While
    End Sub
```

In vs2010 this piece of code is throwing the following error

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024888
  Message=Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

I am from web background so having a little tough time finding a solution for this issue at hand. How can i upgrade this piece to comply with vs2010 and then later to 2013? 
[image]

update #1: 
change the code to

```
While Console.KeyAvailable
            Console.ReadKey(True)
        End While
```

this is resulting in 
[image]

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978091/c-sharp-or-net-flushing-keyboard-buffer   is using `while (Console.KeyAvailable) { Console.ReadKey(true); }`,  not sure  if this is what i need.

Comment: Is your application a Console application?

Comment: no, its a webforms

Comment: The methods on the `Console` class only make sense when a console is attached (i. e. in a Console application).  For a Winforms app, you should handle the appropriate `KeyDown, KeyUp, or KeyPress` events.

Comment: Wanted to avoid individual events and also wanted to keep this old code intact at this time.